# Change name of "List of figures" and "List of Tables"

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

[image]I can't change the english "List of figures" to "Ευρετήριο Εικόνων" and "List of Tables" to "Ευρετήριο Πινάκων", this is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fullpage]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\extrafloats{100}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage[toc]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {/home/Petros/1/} }
\usepackage{longtable,lscape}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Ευρετήριο Εικόνων}} 
\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Εικόνα.}}
\addto\captionsgreek{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Ευρετήριο Πινάκων}}
\newlength{\drop}
%\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,maxnames=1, maxbibnames=99, uniquelist=false, language=english, autolanf=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{titlepage}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} 
\center
\textsc{\large ΑΡΙΣΤΟΤΕΛΕΙΟ ΠΑΝΕΠΙΣΤΗΜΙΟ ΘΕΣΣΑΛΟΝΙΚΗΣ}\\[1.5cm] 
\vspace*{2.2\baselineskip}
\textsc{\large \textbf{ΜΕΤΑΔΙΔΑΚΤΟΡΙΚΗ ΔΙΑΤΡΙΒΗ}}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large Τομέας Παθολογίας και Θεραπευτικής Οδοντικών Ιστών}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large ΕΡΓΑΣΤΗΡΙΟ ΟΔΟΝΤΙΚΗΣ ΧΕΙΡΟΥΡΓΙΚΗΣ}\\[0.5cm] 
\vspace*{2.2\baselineskip}
\HRule \\[0.4cm]
{ \huge \bfseries Μελέτη Της Απελευθέρωσης Μονομερών Από Υλικά \selectlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}\selectlanguage{greek}}\\[0.4cm]
\HRule \\[1.5cm]
\vfill
ΠΕΤΡΟΣ \textsc{ΜΟΥΡΟΥΖΗΣ \selectlanguage{english}{MSc, PhD}
\selectlanguage{greek}} \\
\vspace*{2.2\baselineskip}
{\large \today}\\[2cm] 
\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{auth.jpg} \\
\vfill 
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{Ακρωνύμια} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Ακρωνύμια}

\begin{acronym}[TEGDMA]
\setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}
\acro{BisGMA}[\selectlanguage{english}\textit{BisGMA}]{Γλυκιδυλικός μεθακρυλικός εστέρας της δισφαινόλης Α}
\acro{BPA}[\selectlanguage{english}\textit{BPA}]{Δισφαινόλη Α}
\acro{CQ}[\selectlanguage{english}\textit{CQ}]{Καμφοροκινόνη} 
\end{acronym}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Θεωρητικό Μέρος}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Ιστορικά στοιχεία}
\subsection{Τεχνολογία ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης  και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής.}
\subsection{Αρχικός σχεδιασμός}

\par{\lettrine[lines=2]{Ο}{όρος} της τεχνολογίας ψηφιοποιημένης σχεδίασης και μηχανοποιημένης κοπής ή αλλιώς \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} προσδιορίζει τη συνεργασία ανάμεσα σε ένα σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD} και ένα σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAM} προκειμένου το πρώτο να καθοδηγήσει μια εργαλειομηχανή ηλεκτρονικά ώστε να κατασκευάσει το ψηφιοποιημένο σχέδιο\index{ψηφιοποιημένο σχέδιο}. Για το οδοντιατρικό σύστημα \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} τα δεδομένα προέκυπταν από μια κάμερα ή έναν παντογράφο\index{παντογράφος} ή μια οποιοδήποτε άλλη συσκευή που ψηφιοποιούσε τα δεδομένα που προέκυπταν από το στόμα του ασθενή. Στη συνέχεια ο οδοντίατρος επεξεργαζόταν τα δεδομένα σε μια οθόνη και με τη βοήθεια ενός λογισμικού μπορούσε να κατασκευάσει ψηφιακά την οδοντιατρική αποκατάσταση, η οποία στη συνέχεια κατασκευαζόταν σε ένα κοπτικό μηχάνημα το οποίο ήταν είτε μια ξεχωριστή μονάδα ανεξάρτητη από την κάμερα ή την συσκευή ψηφιοποίησης και τον επεξεργαστή δεδομένων, είτε αποτελούσε ένα ενιαίο τμήμα των παραπάνω. Σχηματικά ο τρόπος λειτουργίας του συστήματος \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} φαίνεται στο παρακάτω σχήμα.}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics[width=14cm]{6.png}
\centering
\caption{Σχηματικά η λογική πίσω από την τεχνολογία \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM} }
\label{Figure:1}
\end{figure}

\selectlanguage{english}
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}
\printbibliography[title=\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}]
\selectlanguage{greek}

\printindex
\newpage
\selectlanguage{greek}
\listoftables
\newpage
\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

Comment: The ToC entry of the list of tables/figures is written when you call `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`, and you use `\selectlanguage{english}` right before doing this, so the `\listfigurename` used is from `\captionsenglish`. Try adding `\selectlanguage{greek}` before `\listoftables`. If that doesn't work, please post a *compilable* working example.

Comment: Yes, that was it. However it gave me an error 

LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item . I look for a missing \item but I don't have any..

Comment: That's a pretty common error in LaTeX, it happens mostly where `\item`s are completely (apparently) unrelated. Then please post a compilable example for we to work on. Also, I assume you are using pdfLaTeX, am I correct?

Comment: Having completed the document with the necessary packages and added  `\end{document}`, I have no problem – but I loaded the language option with `\documentclass`, as is recommended since version 3.10 of babel.

Comment: I think I have upload a compilable example..I use pdflatex..Also, I can't understand why in the TOC the page number in right next to "Βιβλιογραφία" (Reference)

Comment: I posted an answer. This was one strange error :P The number does not appear in the ToC entry for Βιβλιογραφία because there is an error while compiling, so things get messed up.

Comment: @Bernard You didn't get the `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` error because you (I'm guessing) didn't include `tocbibind`. I included it to get the `List of Figures` to appear in the ToC and got the error.

Comment: You're right: I didn't include tocbibind – I believe it was not included in the initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sir, you just discovered my new favorite way of triggering a `Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item` error. Congratulations :)

The culprit of the error is an ordinary typo. This:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}
```

should be

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textgreek{Βιβλιογραφία}}
```

see the lowercase `chapter` there? Yes, that one. The following MWE is enough to trigger the error:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\addcontentsline{toc}{Chapter}{Missing Item}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

to get rid of the error just change `Chapter` to `chapter` and it will work like a charm:

> [image]

---

Now to your code. There are *many* problems with it. I'll list a few:

1. At the `titlepage`: `\center` is not a command, but an environment. The correct usage is `\begin{center}...\end{center}`. If you want the switch, then use `\centering` isntead.
2. Your title:

```
{\huge \bfseries Μελέτη Της Απελευθέρωσης Μονομερών Από Υλικά
 \selectlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}\selectlanguage{greek}}
```

  would look better if you added a
  `\par`
  at the end. This would make the interline spacing correct after the font change "
  `\huge`
  ". Also,
  `\selectlanguage`
  is a switch, so everything after it will be in the set language. No second argument. Use
  `\foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}`
  instead. Then, the
  `\selectlanguage{greek}`
  will be useless too. The same applies for other parts of the
  `titlepage`
  . Use like this:

```
{\huge \bfseries Μελέτη Της Απελευθέρωσης Μονομερών Από Υλικά
 \foreignlanguage{english}{CAD/CAM}\par}
```

3. The most horrifying one. `\par` breaks the paragraph where it is inserted, it does not delimit a paragraph, so it doesn't have an argument. `\par{Some text.}` is wrong. Use `Some text.\par` or just leave a blank line. A blank line is the same as `\par`.
4. You don't need two `\selectlanguage{greek}` there at the end. The effect of `\selectlanguage{greek}` will last until the next language changing command.